# Always starting a div a certain spot from top of current window

Tags: javascript

I have a div that can be revealed from several buttons on the screen. I'd like it so the div always appears 15px from the top of the screen, even if the window is scrolled to the bottom. But, i dont want it to be `fixed`. (meaning you should be able to scroll away from it.

```
#tip {
    background: #fff;
    width: 300px;
    z-index: 100;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: -330px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 0 5px 5px 5px;
}
```

What Javascript solution do I need here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without jQuery, the best I could suggest is this:

```
document.getElementById('tip').style.top = document.scrollTop + 15;
```

Comment: what jQuery would you suggest?

Comment: Not that different: `$('#tip').css('top', $(document).scrollTop() + 15);`

Answer (score 0):

You can try with http://code.google.com/p/jquery-scroll-follow/ - the element will be attached to viewport and will follow it as you scroll http://kitchen.net-perspective.com/sf-example-1.html